# What dependencies should I use to load BottomNavigationView in Android application?

Tags: android

I am trying to add BottomNavigationView to my android application. I have added the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

However, the android application throws a runtime exception when we run the application. Also, the autocomplete option in the xml file is not autocompleting the BottomNavigationView component which means the component BottomNavigationView is somehow not getting loaded in the project.

How may I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate cache or clean/rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer" />
```

try this, and do not forget to hit "sync project with gradle"